# Storing strings from a text file into a two dimensional array

Tags: c, arrays, string

I'm working on a project using C and for the project I must read in a text file and store each word into an array. I also have to remove the punctuation off the words, so I need to use a 2-Dimensional array in order to edit the words. I am having trouble figuring out how to get the words in the 2-D array it self. This is what I have done so far:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#define MAX 1001
#define LINES 81

int main(void) {
    int stringSize;
    int i =0;
    char *x[MAX][LINES];
    char str[MAX];
    char y[MAX];
    FILE *fp;

    fp = fopen("TwoCitiesStory.txt","r");
    if(fp == NULL) {
        printf("Cannot open file.\n");
        exit(1);
    }

    while(!feof(fp)) {
        for(i=0;i<MAX;i++){
            fscanf(fp,"%s",x[i][LINES]);
        }
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Do you want to read a line from file... as %s will only read words

Comment: For example if the text file contained "Hi my name is Bob". I need the array to hold x[0][]="Hi" x[1][]="my" and so on. The maximum amount of words in the text file is 1000 and the maximum length of a word is 80 characters.

Comment: so what problem are you facing with this code

Comment: `char x[MAX][LINES];`..`for(i=0;i<MAX;i++){   fscanf(fp,"%80s",x[i]); }`

Comment: You are using `feof` incorrectly: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5431941/while-feof-file-is-always-wrong

Comment: "Cannot open file." is the canonical useless error message: `FILE * Fopen(const char *path, const char *mode) { FILE *fp = fopen(path, mode); if( fp == NULL) {perror(path); exit( EXIT_FAILURE);} return fp; }`

Comment: Why do you think you need arrays at all?  What are you actually trying to do with the data?

Comment: After I store the data in the array, for example if the text file contained "Hi my name is Bob". I need the array to hold x[0][]="Hi" x[1][]="my" and so on. I will have a have another file with a list of words, and I will compare and see how many times the words in the list appear in the first file.

Comment: Just a heads up, whether you read a `line` at a time, or a `word` at a time, your punctuation removal will be virtually identical. After having your text stored in either a 2-D array of chars or an array of pointers to string, you will create a temporary string (say `tmp`) long enough to hold the word/line and then step through the word/line copying each char that is not punctuation to `tmp`. When done, replace your word/line with `tmp` (null-terminate if `tmp` is a line). Then repeat for each word/line.

Answer (score 1):

1. Read the whole line using `fgets()`
2. Store the read line into the 2D array

The whole code looks like

```
char x[row][col];
char buf[300];
int i=0,j=0;
memset(x,0,sizeof(x));
while(fgets(buf,sizeof(buf),fp))
{
  size_t n = strlen(buf);
  if(n>0 && buf[n-1] == '\n')
  buf[n-1] = '\0';
  if(i>= row && n> col)
  break;
  strcpy(x[i],buf);
  i++;

}
```

**Edits:**

If you need each word separately in the array.
`buf` is being used to read the whole line.
`strtok()` is used to break the line into words with space as delimiter.
Then store each word in each row.

```
size_t n;
while(fgets(buf,sizeof(buf),fp))
{
   char *p = strtok(buf," ");
   while( p != NULL)
   {
      n = strlen(p);
      if(i>= row && n> col)
      break;
      strcpy(x[i],p);
      i++;
      p = strtok(NULL," ");
   }
}
```

If you want to print out the array go for

```
int i;
for(i=0;i<row;i++)
printf("%s\n",x[i]);
```

[Why feof() is wrong](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5431941/while-feof-file-is-always-wrong)

Comment: This doesn't separate each word in the array.  
For example if the text file contained "Hi my name is Bob". I need the array to hold x[0][]="Hi" x[1][]="my" and so on. The maximum amount of words in the text file is 1000 and the maximum length of a word is 80 characters.

Comment: The code it self runs successfully, but I am a bit confused on how you reached this answer. Is row the max number of words and col the length of the words themselves?  First you created char x[row][col]; which created an array of characters and then you created buf[300];. But what does buf do? If I have to print the words after, which array do I call? I tried printing like this: for(i=0;i<row;i++) 
                                    for(i=0;i<col;i++)
                                          printf("%s\n",x[row][col]);

Comment: @beginner_coder You can print out the 2D array as shown in the edits

Answer (score 1):

The following line

```
char *x[MAX][LINES];
```

declared a 2D array of pointers. What you need is just a 2D array of characters.

```
char x[MAX][LINES];
```

The code for reading the words can be simplified to:

```
while( i < MAX && fscanf(fp, "%80s", x[i]) == 1 )
{
   ++i;
}
```